# Neuter a cat allowed in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, pets

Is neutering a male cat allowed in Islam. I have heard people saying that it will hurt the cat so it is not allowed. But vet(pet doctor) says

> **Veterinarians provide cats with general anesthesia so the surgery itself is painless. Any discomfort a cat experiences afterward is minimal and part of the normal healing process. Most cats recover quickly, resuming normal activity within three days** -
>   [Reference](https://www.petcha.com/spay-and-neuter-facts/)

The problem we are facing is that cats do spray urine in house when they are in heat which makes our house **Putrid / Napak**. Another reason we find to neuter  our cat is that he makes loud noises (Yowling) which really annoys family members. Our pet is 1 year old and we raised him. We don't want to give him to somebody else as we think giving it to the wrong person may effect his health because pets require constant attention and food.

I would also like to mention that the cat is anxious and his behavior has changed a lot, which we think is not good for him as he has started fighting with cats outside the house, he tries to runaway from house because of female cat(he was injured because he jumped off from roof and did't land correctly.)
Started spraying urine in house. Hair loss, loss of appetite, etc. That is why we think it will be a good decision to neuter him.

Some people say it is right to get your pet neutered because of the following reasons I mentioned above. Some people shared Quranic Verses but that didn't exactly prohibited neutering of pets.

Thanks.